# CreateRemoteThread failing with ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY

Tags: c++, windows, service

This is quite strange question, but, I believe, this is on-topic for SO.

**Intro:**

I have an service, written in C#, which calls my C++ library. C++ library execute some 3rdparty software via `WinExec`.

3rdparty software injects DLL via `CreateRemoteThread`. I don't have source files for this software.

**Main part**

I have 2 PCs - Win2008 and Win10.

For Win10 - this frankenstein is working flawlessly, Service runs DLL, DLL runs 3rdparty DLL injector, DLL injector injects stuff.

For Win2008 things are different. If I run 3rdparty DLL injector from CMD - it works flawlessly. But if I run service - Injector returns, that he got ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY from CreateRemoteThread.

Service is working from LocalService account, and everything is OK on Windows 10. I am looking for possible ideas\clues, why there is a problem with SERVICE (remember, CMD works fine) and ONLY for Windows 2008.

Answer (score 3):

This issue might be related to creating a remote thread across privilege levels, as explained in the following blog article:

[Injecting Code Into Privileged Win32 Processes](http://mnin.blogspot.com/2007/05/injecting-code-into-privileged-win32.html)

> With XP SP2 and later (2003, Vista) some new security measures prevent the traditional CreateRemoteThread() function from working properly. You should be able to open the process, allocate memory on its heap, and write data to the allocated region, but when trying to invoke the remote thread, it will fail with ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY.
>
> ...
>
> For XP SP2 I did a little debugging and found that inside CreateRemoteThread(), there is a call to ZwCreateThread() which is an export from ntdll.dll. The call is made while specifying that the thread should start suspended, which it does properly, however down the road still inside CreateRemoteThread() before ZwResumeThread() is called, there is a call to CsrClientCallServer() which fails and eventually leads to the error message.

The article explains some different ways of injecting remote threads on different version of Windows to avoid the error, ending with this conclusion:

> At this point, we can successfully execute remote threads into privileged processes across all target platforms, but as mentioned before, its pretty messy. We're using three different, largely undocumented functions and auto-detecting which one to use based on the OS version.
>
> The better solution is to create a secondary program that adds a service object (your injector program) to the service control manager database on the target system. Since you're administrator, which is required anyway, you'll be able to add these entries and start the service. This will enable the injector program to run with different access rights than normal code, and the traditional CreateRemoteThread() will work properly on Windows 2000, all of XP, and 2003/Vista. The API functions for adding and controlling the service are documented by MSDN and remain consistent across all of the platforms.
>
> So, what is learned is that we can use a number of different functions to inject code into privileged remote processes, including RtlCreateUserThread() on XP SP2, and NtCreateThreadEx() on Vista, but the optimal way is to install a temporary service and allow CreateRemoteThread() to be the single API that accomplishes the task for all platforms.

Of course, none of this really matters since you don't have the source code for the injector and thus cannot change how it works.

Also, you can't create remote threads across session boundaries, either.  Calling `WinExec()` in a service will run the injector process in the same session as the service, ie session 0.  If it is trying to inject into a process that is running in a user session, that will never work.  This would also explain why running the injector from CMD works, if CMD is running in the same session as the process that is being injected into.

Comment: Thanks for input. But my main concern, that everything is working under Windows 10. Might it be some Windows 2008 settings or similar stuff?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue today and this seems to be the issue-

> Prior to Windows 8, Terminal Services isolates each terminal session by design. Therefore, CreateRemoteThread fails if the target process is in a different session than the calling process.

This explains why your code works on Windows 10 but not on Windows 7/2008.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405484(v=vs.85).aspx